# android - How to display the message

Tags: android

Please see the following image. In android how to display this type of messages? is it possiable.
Can anybody help me

[message image](http://s1185.photobucket.com/albums/z352/repalle/?albumview=slideshow)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in your application or in browser? Im not sure if this is what your looking for but i would try using notifications. Hopefully this helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: My App is refreshing every 40 sec at that time i want to display this type message is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why your app is refreshing the UI every 40 sec? In either case if you call .notify each time your app refreshes the notification would pop up again. Also im not certain but i think the notification would stay up even if you refresh your app.

Comment: if you check the link above, it leads you through how to create a basic notification. Personally im not to familiar with them, because i haven't used them a lot, i tend to use Toasts or Dialogs, but those wouldn't help you in your case